# VBA - Method 'delete' of worksheet failing

Tags: vba, excel

I made a VBA program and now that everything is done I need to clean my workbook completely to run the program several times. For this I am using this code:

```
Sub deleteWorksheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Delete
Next ws

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

But the method delete is failing every time. I tried to activate before and set the visible property, nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to let at least one worksheet survive the purge. You can't delete them all.

Try something like this:

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
        ws.Delete
    Else
        ' in case you want to wipe out whatever was in the sheet
        ws.Cells.Clear
    End If
Next ws
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was trying to delete everything at once.. Now works fine.