# Delete worksheets on every pc

Tags: excel, vba

I've written a simple VBA sub that deletes a couple of worksheets while keeping some others when the user clicks a button. **If I use it on my pc it works perfectly** but it doesn't run on the pc of the person I've written the macro for. The error message the person gets is:

> "Method 'Delete' of object '_Worksheet' failed.

This is **the macro**:

---

```
Sub deleteWorksheets()

Dim wb                      As Workbook
Dim wks                     As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each wks In wb.Worksheets
    If wks.Name <> "A" And wks.Name <> "B" And wks.Name <> "C" Then
        wks.Delete
    End If
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

---

The sheets A, B, C are included in the workbook. So that's ok. He sent me his references and I see he uses:

- Microsoft Excel  14.0 Object Library  where I use Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library  where I use Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library

Anybody who faced a similar issue?

**Update**:

A hidden sheet created by a third party software add-in created the issue. As I don't have that software installed I don't have the issue.

Modifying code to:

---

```
Sub deleteWorksheets()

Dim wb                      As Workbook
Dim wks                     As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each wks In wb.Worksheets
    If wks.Name <> "A" And wks.Name <> "B" And wks.Name <> "C" And wks.Name <> "__FDSCACHE__" Then
        wks.Delete
    End If
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

---

---

solved the issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17581126/11683?

Comment: The worksheets 'A' , 'B' and 'C' are in the workbook. It works fine on my pc. I'm puzzled why it doesn't work on the other pc

Comment: Because on the other pc there is no worksheets A, B or C?

Comment: No. He uses the workbook (including sheets and macro) I've send him.

Comment: Error  `1004  - Method 'Delete' of object '_Worksheet' failed` is generated when the Worksheet to be deleted is the only worksheet in the workbook.

Comment: So based on the other comments, either count how many sheets are there and add one if needed or just add a blank sheet anyway...

Comment: @SolarMike any worksheet named different than "A", "B" or "C" will be deleted.

Comment: Does it fail on one specific sheet?  If you re-order the sheets does it fail the same way?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to guide the user remotely for the debugging which complicates stuff. Anyhow, I've put a watch on the variable wks. Checking the wks.Name attribute I noticed he had '_FDSCACHE_' where I had wks.Name = 'A'. The _FDSCACHE_ is apparently a hidden worksheet created by third party software (add-ins). I guess trying to delete that causes the issue. Will keep you posted.